# Swift app crashes when comparing two values

Tags: swift, casting

```
func isPurchasedBDEBasicPass() -> Bool {
    var isPurchased = false
    IAPHelper.sharedInstance.productIdentifiers.forEach { product in
        if let purchasedProduct = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: product.rawValue) {
            if purchasedProduct as! String == Product.BDEbasicPass.rawValue { // Crash here
                // remove ads
                isPurchased = true
            }
        }
    }
    return isPurchased
}
```

I get a crash here

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSCFBoolean' (0x1fcb91c70) to 'NSString' (0x1fcb9d170).
```

I casted both as String

Product is an enum

```
public enum Product: String, CaseIterable {
     case BDEbasicPass = "abc"
}
```

Comment: What is it you store in UserDefaults ?

Comment: At some point (since you have a loop (why?) `purchasedProduct` is a `Bool` not a `String`.

Comment: And you should use either the access method that is specific for your type like `string(forKey:)` or the general `object(forKey)` and cast the result but not `value(forKey:)`

Comment: purchasedProduct is Bool. Check what you are puting to UserDefaults